# How to dynamically create DataTable columns from names and types in lists of strings?

Tags: c#, string, types, datatable, tablecolumn

I would like to add columns to a existing `DataTable`.

However, the name of the new column and the type, came from a string list.

```
ColumnName_list = FieldX, FieldY ...

ColumnType_list = Sistem.String, System.Decimal ...
```

The order is always related between the two lists.

I am trying to use the code below, however is getting type error conversion

```
t = 0;
foreach (var name in ColumnName_list)  
{   
    dt1.Columns.Add(name, ColumnType_list[t]);
    t++;
}
```

> Compiler error at line 27: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Type'

Where `Dt1` is the `Datatable`.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: `System.Type` sounds like the data type list has a bad entry or perhaps your code is interpreting a header.  Debug and check.  Hopefully `Sistem.String` is a posting artifact only

Answer (score -2):

May you try

```
    t = 0;
    foreach (var name in ColumnName_list)  
    {   
     dt1.Columns.Add(name, typeof(ColumnType_list[t]) );
     t++;
    }
```

May you share the result after you try

Have a nice day

Comment: This returns another error. Saying that I am missing ")" or ";".